# Filtering a list to take its highest values

Tags: python

I have a program which works with a for loop, but it's too slow, and I need to speed it up.

I have a reverse-sorted list of probabilities whose sum is 1.  There are over 5 million items.

I want to take the highest probabilities, i.e. the first n items whose collective sum is 0.9999.

This was my code:

```
for b in sorted_list:
   new_list.append(b)
     if sum(new_list) > 0.9999:
       break
```

Can anyone suggest a quicker method?

Thank you

Edit:  I found that this question was asked before - [stackexchange link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12753/taking-the-first-few-items-of-a-list-until-a-target-sum-is-exceeded)

however, the suggestions all make use of loops so I don't think they will be any quicker.  Someone at the end suggested a list comprehension. So I am going to google that and see what that means!  Thank you

Comment: This is a classic mistake, `sum(new_list)` every step makes your algorithm very inefficient. Instead, just keep score adding the appended element to the previous total.

Comment: can you try np.array(sorted_list)[np.cumsum(sorted_list)< 0.9999]

Comment: I like the idea that I made a classic mistake.  Going to replace my code with the suggestion below and check the outcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep a running sum instead of recomputing it every step for the whole list. I.e.

```
running_sum = 0
for b in sorted_list:
    new_list.append(b)
    running_sum += b
    if running_sum > 0.9999:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick replies.  

I am going to try this solution.  I haven't yet had time to digest why you all think this is quicker, but I will certainly try it, and after I have done it, I'll have probably figured out why my process was inefficient.

I will probably come back in an an hour or so and uptick this as solution, but I want to try it first

Thanks to all for your comments.

Comment: The version provided in your question requires that all elements in `new_list` are accessed to perform addition to compute the sum on each iteration. This computes in `O(n!)` time over the course of all iterations. However, the incremental addition only needs to perform a single operation with each iteration of the loop, meaning it performs in `O(n)` time. This presents a significant speedup as the size of `n` gets large.

Comment: @JacobTurpin The complexity is quadratic, not exponential as you suggest. Simple nested iteration issue. For every outer iteration, the collected inner items are iterated. That amounts to an `O(n^2)` complexity.

Comment: Thanks Jacob.  I understand now why the amendment is so much faster.

Answer (score 4):

[`sum(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) has to visit all elements to calculate the sum. That is unnecessary as you can reuse the sum from the previous iteration.
The built-in tool to accumulate such a sum is, well, [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate). Moreover, you don't have to append repeatedly. Instead, you can take a single slice at the end:

```
 from itertools import accumulate

 for i, s in enumerate(accumulate(sorted_list)):
     if s > 0.9999:
         break
 new_list = sorted_list[:i+1]
```